# Excel and VBA Gives Different Answers

Tags: excel, vba

I have faced a strange issue(Maybe a bug) at Data Validation

When i use below code for data validation, Excel is creating a dropdown but add string as one line. But when i write the same string from Excel data validation menu, Excel is seperating the dropdown with multiple items which i want.
For example, lets say string is "A;B;C"
When i do it by VBA, dropdown shows "A;B;C" as 1 line but when i click data validation menu and write manually "A;B;C" , Excel is creating 3 lines of dropdown with "A" , "B" , "C"
It is totally strange behavior. You may see the code as below. I add video link to explain better. 
https://streamable.com/a75kud

```
Public arrAddress As String
Sub DynamicDataVal()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cll As Range
Dim dValicationCount As Long
Dim un As String
Dim DValidationList As Range
Dim DValidationListString As String
Dim seper As String
Dim col As New Collection, a
Dim colIt As Variant
Dim arr() As Variant

un = "Sayin " & Environ("UserName")

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Lutfen Veri Alanini Seciniz", un, ActiveCell.Address, , , , , 8)
If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set cll = ActiveCell
dValicationCount = cll.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Count

If dValicationCount = 0 Then
    arr = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Resize(, 1).Cells.Count - 1, 1).Value
    arrAddress = rng.Address(External:=True)
    For Each a In arr
       col.Add a, a
    Next a
    seper = ListSeperatorMod.GetListSeparator
    For Each colIt In col
         DValidationListString = DValidationListString & seper & colIt
    Next colIt
    DValidationListString = Right(DValidationListString, Len(DValidationListString) - 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    With cll.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:=DValidationListString
    End With
Else
    If rng.Validation.Type <> 3 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Will be done
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" _
    (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetUserDefaultLCID% Lib "kernel32" ()
Private Const LOCALE_SLIST = &HC

Public Function GetListSeparator() As String

    Dim ListSeparator As String
    Dim iRetVal1 As Long
    Dim iRetVal2 As Long
    Dim lpLCDataVar As String

    Dim Position As Integer
    Dim Locale As Long

    Locale = GetUserDefaultLCID()

    iRetVal1 = GetLocaleInfo(Locale, LOCALE_SLIST, lpLCDataVar, 0)

    ListSeparator = String$(iRetVal1, 0)

    iRetVal2 = GetLocaleInfo(Locale, LOCALE_SLIST, ListSeparator, iRetVal1)

    Position = InStr(ListSeparator, Chr$(0))
    If Position > 0 Then
        ListSeparator = Left$(ListSeparator, Position - 1)
    End If

    GetListSeparator = ListSeparator

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design and it's the the same behavior you'd see if using VBA to enter a formula in a cell: you always use the "US" list separator `,` in VBA, and not (eg) the locale-specific separator  such as `;`.

This differs from entering a formula via the user interface, where you're always using the locale-specific separator.

So in VBA you might use:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=MAX(A1, B2)"
```

and if your locale separator is `;` then the formula shows up on the sheet as:

```
=MAX(A1; B2)
```

This alows the same VBA to function across different locales without modifications